# Sitecore - Digizuite workflow coordination

Tags: workflow

How does one tie in Digizuite workflow into a Sitecore workflow to approve content assets along with related digital management assets? I've been able to create an approval workflow in Digizuite but cannot for the life of me figure out how to both

1. Activate it
2. Associate it with a Sitecore workflow for approvals of all assets.

Comment: Probably better off asking DigiZuite/House & Co for advice on this but I imagine you'll need to add some Sitecore Workflow steps which run custom code to "do stuff" using the DigiZuite API.

I guess you'd need to look for DigiZuite fields and then pick out the asset ids, then send those to DigiZuite in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Checked this question with Digizuite as it was indeed an interesting one. As Owen mentions above, they indeed want you to hook into their API and listen for whatever event is relevent for you. They recommend to start a Proof of Concept for this. Key is to use their own API. I got this (high level) info from John Burke-Hansen so you best get in touch with him to work out an approach to this.